# Match fields and group by column value into 1 line

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with multiple columns separated by `|` as shown below. The file has about 30 million records.

## Text.log

```
100001|2000001|1000|C_ER|200|20200525075521|20370101000000|20200525075521
100001|2000001|1000|C_TPT|800|20200525075521|20370101000000|20200525075521

100001|3000001|1000|C_CED|100|20200525080051|20370101000000|20200525080051
100001|3000001|1000|C_CSD|50|20200525080051|20370101000000|20200525080051
100001|3000001|1000|C_SIN|2000|20200525080051|20370101000000|20200525080051

100001|4000001|1000|C_CED|DATE|20200531070527|20370101000000|20200531070527
100001|4000001|1000|C_CSD|NUMB|20200531070527|20370101000000|20200531070527
100001|4000001|1000|C_SIN|20BIN|20200531070527|20370101000000|20200531070527
100001|4000001|1000|C_PON|192|20200531070527|20370101000000|20200531070527
```

I want to merge the record into 1 line if column 2 & column 3 are in the same category.

Here is the output:

## Output

```
100001|2000001|1000|C_ER|200|C_TPT|800|20200525075521|20370101000000|20200525075521

100001|3000001|1000|C_CED|100|C_CSD|50|C_SIN|2000|20200525080051|20370101000000|20200525080051

100001|4000001|1000|C_CED|DATE|C_CSD|NUMB|C_SIN|20BIN|C_PON|192|20200531070527|20370101000000|20200531070527
```

I used this code to extract the records and sort them, but I can't merge them into single lines for the same record category:

```
cat cbs_bc_offering_prop_all*|grep 100740000001755144|awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=SUBSEP="|"}{arr[$2,$3,$4,$6,$7,$8,$9,$12,$15] }END {for (i in arr) print i,arr[i]}'|sort -t'|' -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3
```

Comment: Please add a better description of how they should be merged. Also, column 2 and 3 are equal in line 1 and 2. Why don't you show them in your example output ?

Comment: column 1,2,3,6,7,8 are identical and unique, whereas column 4,5 has different values and need to merge them together.

Comment: input
======
100001|4000001|1000|C_CED|DATE|20200531070527|20370101000000|20200531070527
100001|4000001|1000|C_CSD|NUMB|20200531070527|20370101000000|20200531070527
100001|4000001|1000|C_SIN|20BIN|20200531070527|20370101000000|20200531070527
100001|4000001|1000|C_PON|192|20200531070527|20370101000000|20200531070527

output 
=======
100001|4000001|1000|C_CED|DATE|C_CSD|NUMB|C_SIN|20BIN|C_PON|192|20200531070527|20370101000000|20200531070527

Comment: Edit the question itself, don't use the comments to correct input/output

Comment: Are only consecutive lines to be merged?

Comment: Do those blank lines **really** exist in your input and output? If not then [edit] your question to get rid of them.

Comment: Will there be a scenario when columns 6,7, or 8 differ? And if so what heuristics to be applied fir merging them? You should state all these things up front and in a clear, concise, and crisp manner alongwith the various input combinations and their expected output, otherwise there'll be a lot of needless iterations.

Comment: script below works for me case.. and my bad for unclear info .. tq

Answer (score 2):

Im sure we can make this cleaner but...make it work part its done.

Basically, the we split the fields and the merge them again, hope it helps!

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {FS="|"; output_data=""; ofs="|"}

function data_splitter () {split($0,splited_data,"|")
header=splited_data[1] "|" splited_data[2] "|" splited_data[3]
data=splited_data[4] "|" splited_data[5]
tail=splited_data[NF-2] "|" splited_data[NF-1] "|" splited_data[NF]
}

function data_dump(reg1, reg2, reg3) {
output_header=reg1
output_data=output_data reg2 ofs
output_tail=reg3
}

#MAIN
NR==1{
data_splitter()
data_dump(header, data, tail)
next
}

{
if (splited_data[2]==$2){
data_splitter()
data_dump(header, data, tail)}

else{
print output_header ofs output_data output_tail
output_data=""

data_splitter()
data_dump(header, data, tail)
}
}

END{
print output_header ofs output_data output_tail
}
```

Comment: yup, this is the expected results.. however, i change a bit in the requirement and has posted another question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602579/awk-extract-and-group-by-column-value-into-single-line

Comment: much appreciated the solutions.. :)